# In Windows Communication Framework when is it better to define client configuration in XML rather than programmatically?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am just learning how to use WCF services and I started by following the 6 step tutorial at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms734712.aspx). In part 4 the use of svcutil.exe to generate client code is discussed <s>and part 5 shows a big nasty looking XML file that configures the WCF client</s>. Using svcutil.exe <s>and this XML</s> just seems so heavy relative to the very simple solution I've adopted for my WCF demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WSHttpBinding bhb = new WSHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/index/ServiceReference1");
        ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IDemoChannel> cf = new ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IDemoChannel>(bhb, epa);

        cf.Open(); 
        ServiceReference1.IDemoChannel channel = cf.CreateChannel();
        channel.Open();

        String s = channel.getHelloWorld(5);
        channel.Close();
        cf.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", s);
        Console.WriteLine("I'm the client! Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

<s>Having seen these two very different ways of configuring a client, I wonder what is the benefit of using generated code and XML files and when is it better than the programmatic approach?</s>

UPDATE: I've re-read the XML file in part 5 of the tutorial, and it seems that the XML file was duplicated and looking at the intended XML I retract the XML aspect of my question. I think what I'm really asking is "Why would I want to generate my code using svcutil.exe when writing client code doesn't seem so bad"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the ease with which you can change xml configuration, another huge benefit of svcutil (or adding a service reference to a project) is the auto generated types required by and returned from the wcf methods which are available to you without referencing the declaring assembly. In hello world examples where the method returns a string this doesnt matter, but large wcf implementations may have many request/response types.

Comment: I agree that automatically getting the data types would be useful, but why wouldn't I put the types into a library that can be referenced by any program needing to use the types?

Comment: Sometimes its not an option - if you dont have access to the type assembly (eg calling a remote service from another company).

Comment: To ensure I understand you correctly I have two follow up qustions: 1. If I'm developing services for my company and I make libraries to hold the types being used and make them available to other developers, there would be no need for svcutil? 2. Whereas if I am calling an existing service that hasn't been designed that way, I can use svcutil to generate the code I would need?

Comment: 1-you wouldnt need svcutil but it is still easier than hand crafting code i think. 2 - it simplifies things by generating the proxies etc.   I think for simple cases your approach is fine, with large solutions which may need to change bindings its impractical.

Comment: OK I'll start by apologizing for all these follow-up questions, but this is all very useful for me. Can you give me an example of what you mean when you say "large solutions which may need to change bindings"?

Comment: Enterprise solutions with many endpoints, where server addresses change between test, uat, production - or security implementations change - or transport. All of this is made easier by xml configuration

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion : **Always use an XML** because you can change that after your program has been deployed and you just need to restart your service.

If you use your demo code you'll need to **rebuild, recompile, redeploy,** etc. and that's a lot **slower** than using an **XML**.

Comment: What you say makes sense. I think what I'm really asking is why should I use svcutil.exe when writing my own code seems so easy? I've updated my question to reflect this. Sorry to waste your time on a not-fully-thought-through question...

Answer (score 0):

> "Why would I want to generate my code using svcutil.exe when writing
>   client code doesn't seem so bad"?

When you are writing a simple test program, what you have done in code works well.

When you develop a larger application that requires a team and maintenance over time, the xml configuration is the better choice. Imagine the service is written and maintained by a completely different team and they won't let you read their code. The client configuration has to exactly match the configuration on the service. When the service team changes uri, or port, or use certificates (https) how will you as the client developer find out? The call will fail (likely with a very uninformative error message). How do you fix it? Just run svcutil again and regenerate the configuration. No need to call a meeting, read (hopefully) updated documentation, etc.

Coming back to you sample test code you posted: The moment your service reaches the point of being deployed somewhere other than localhost and you have to recompile the client for no other reason than to update the url... that's when you will begin to understand the value of defining connection information in configuration. Until then, don't worry about it.